# Trying to compile gnupg from source

Tags: bash, permissions, compiling, gnupg

I downloaded the latest stable tarball from https://www.gnupg.org/download/ and extracted it to a folder on my ubuntu machine.
I had to chmod 775 configure in order to be able to run it, then I ran ./configure

I got this message right at the end:

```
    GnuPG v2.0.29 has been configured as follows:


    Revision:  120fc69  (4623)
    Platform:  GNU/Linux (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)


    OpenPGP:   yes
    S/MIME:    yes
    Agent:     yes 
    Smartcard: yes (without internal CCID driver)
    Gpgtar:    no


    Protect tool:      (default)
    Default agent:     (default)
    Default pinentry:  (default)
    Default scdaemon:  (default)
    Default dirmngr:   (default)


    Warning: Mismatches between the target platform and the
             to be used libraries have been detected for:
               libgpg-error libgcrypt
             Please check above for more warning messages.
```

I tried to run a sudo apt-get install libgpg-error libgcrypt but it said they couldn't be found, so I tried libgpg-error-dev libgcrypt-dev and got this:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
libgpg-error-dev is already the newest version.
libgcrypt11-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 69 not upgraded.
```

So I tried to run make and this is what I saw at the very end

```
Making all in .
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/nitrous/gnupg-new/tests'
srcdir=. GNUPGHOME=`/bin/pwd` GPG_AGENT_INFO= LC_ALL=C GPGSM=../sm/gpgsm ./runtest ./inittests
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/nitrous/gnupg-new/tests'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/nitrous/gnupg-new/tests'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/nitrous/gnupg-new'
/bin/bash: ./runtest: permission denied
make[3]: *** [inittests.stamp] Error 126
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
Making all in .
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/nitrous/gnupg-new/tests'
srcdir=. GNUPGHOME=`/bin/pwd` GPG_AGENT_INFO= LC_ALL=C GPGSM=../sm/gpgsm ./runtest ./inittests
/bin/bash: ./runtest: Permission denied
make[3]: *** [inittests.stamp] Error 126
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/nitrous/gnupg-new/tests'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/nitrous/gnupg-new/tests'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/nitrous/gnupg-new'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I then ran make install and got the same error at the end. What is going wrong?

Edit:

I've manually compiled and installed libgpg-error and libgcrypt, the ./configure went fine without any warnings, when I ran `sudo make` I got this at the end:

```
chmod 755 ./gpg_dearmor
./gpg_dearmor > ./pubring.gpg < ./pubring.asc
../../g10/gpg2: error while loading shared libraries: libgcrypt.so.20: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [pubring.gpg] Error 127
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/nitrous/gnupg-new/tests/openpgp'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/nitrous/gnupg-new/tests'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/nitrous/gnupg-new'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Then when I tried make install again, I got this:

```
Making install in tests
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/nitrous/gnupg-new/tests'
Making install in openpgp
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/nitrous/gnupg-new/tests/openpgp'
./gpg_dearmor > ./secring.gpg < ./secring.asc
../../g10/gpg2: error while loading shared libraries: libgcrypt.so.20: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [secring.gpg] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/nitrous/gnupg-new/tests/openpgp'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/nitrous/gnupg-new/tests'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Edit 2:

I found a post that said to run `sudo ldconfig -v`

And then when I ran `./configure` and `sudo make install` again I was given this error at the end:

```
Making all in .
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/nitrous/gnupg-new/tests'
srcdir=. GNUPGHOME=`/bin/pwd` GPG_AGENT_INFO= LC_ALL=C GPGSM=../sm/gpgsm ./runtest ./inittests
/bin/bash: ./runtest: Permission denied
make[3]: *** [inittests.stamp] Error 126
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/nitrous/gnupg-new/tests'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/nitrous/gnupg-new/tests'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/nitrous/gnupg-new'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Edit 3:

I ran a `sudo chmod 755 on tests/runtest` and did `./configure` and `sudo make` AGAIN and now I have this error:

```
Making all in .
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/nitrous/gnupg-new/tests'
srcdir=. GNUPGHOME=`/bin/pwd` GPG_AGENT_INFO= LC_ALL=C GPGSM=../sm/gpgsm ./runtest ./inittests
asschk: interpreter: invalid statement `set'
make[3]: *** [inittests.stamp] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/nitrous/gnupg-new/tests'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/nitrous/gnupg-new/tests'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/nitrous/gnupg-new'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

*Sigh*....

Comment: You'll probably also have to compile and install `libgpg-error` and `libgcrypt`. Though I'm surprised you had to do `chmod 775 configure` - the tarball should already have an executable `configure`.

Comment: @muru I have done that and edited my original post with the results.

Comment: @muru fwiw it appears to configure and build successfully on my 64-bit 14.04 box with the standard repo versions of libgcrypt20-dev and libgpg-error-dev - I didn't need to install any newer dependencies from source.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mattrude/3883a3801613b048d45b

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the provided speedo method the easiest for gnupg-2.1.X:

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install libldap2-dev gtk+-2 libbz2-dev`
3. after unpacking the latest gnupg-2.1.X tarball and cd to the new folder, run the command:

   ```
   sudo make -f build-aux/speedo.mk native INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
   ```
4. `sudo ldconfig`
5. download the latest pinentry-0.9.5, run `./configure && make && sudo make install`.
6. test it out:  `gpg2 --version`

****I would like to update this answer for GnuPG v2.2.x.  The following bash file will install on Ubuntu 16.04, 17.10:

```
cd ~/Downloads
version=gnupg-2.2.2
wget https://gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/gnupg/$version.tar.bz2
wget https://gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/gnupg/$version.tar.bz2.sig
tar xf $version.tar.bz2
cd $version
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y libldap2-dev
sudo apt-get install -y gtk+-2
sudo apt-get install -y rng-tools
sudo apt-get install -y libbz2-dev
sudo apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libgmp-dev
sudo apt-get install -y nettle-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libgnutls28-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libsqlite3-dev
sudo apt-get install -y adns-tools
sudo apt-get install -y libreadline-dev
sudo apt-get install -y pinentry-gtk2
sudo apt-get install -y pcscd scdaemon
sudo make -f build-aux/speedo.mk native INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
sudo ldconfig
```

This will support TOFU and Smart Cards like Yubikey 4 Nano.
To update to the [newest version](https://www.gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/gnupg/) edit **version=gnupg-2.2.2** 
Test it: gpg --version

Comment: What do you mean download pinentry? Do I run those commands in pinentry to install it? Or do I install pinentry and then run those commands in gnupg? What does pinentry do?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I was typing in gpg instead of gpg2 (idiot). Thanks!

Comment: To be complete - yes download pinentry tarball, unpack, cd to new directory, and run ./configure etc to install it.  Pinentry is not necessary to compile GnuPG but it is needed to enter passphrases interactively.