# Can't add PPA? for y-ppa-manager on 17.04

Tags: ppa, gnupg, 17.04

I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04 and i want to add the y-ppa-manager but when i run the command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
```

I get the following error:

```
gpg: connecting dirmngr at '/tmp/tmp8h5gt_of/S.dirmngr'
failed: IPC 
connect call failed
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr
Failed to add key.
```

But I see that I already have `dirmngr`. I tried to uninstall and reinstall it but that doesn't work. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that i needed to actually update my gnupg version.
I followed the instructions here and was able to do so.

[Trying to compile gnupg from source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/681041/trying-to-compile-gnupg-from-source)

Here are the steps:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libldap2-dev gtk+-2 libbz2-dev
```

after unpacking the latest gnupg-2.1.X tarball and cd to the new folder, run the command:

```
sudo make -f build-aux/speedo.mk native INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
sudo ldconfig
```

download the latest pinentry-0.9.5, run `./configure && make && sudo make install.`

test it out:  `gpg2 --version`

After that you can add the PPA with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
```

Download the gnupg tarball from [here](https://www.gnupg.org/download/index.en.html)

Answer (score 0):

Backup your existing directories:  $HOME/.gnupg and /root/.gnupg and remove them.

```
# dirmngr --debug-level guru
dirmngr[20243.0]: error opening '/root/.gnupg/dirmngr_ldapservers.conf': No such file or directory
dirmngr[20243.0]: permanently loaded certificates: 0
dirmngr[20243.0]:     runtime cached certificates: 0
dirmngr[20243.0]: failed to open cache dir file '/root/.gnupg/dirmngr-cache.d/DIR.txt': No such file or directory
dirmngr[20243.0]: creating directory '/root/.gnupg'
dirmngr[20243.0]: creating directory '/root/.gnupg/dirmngr-cache.d'
dirmngr[20243.0]: new cache dir file '/root/.gnupg/dirmngr-cache.d/DIR.txt' created
dirmngr[20243.0]: DBG: chan_3 -> # Home: ~/.gnupg
# Home: ~/.gnupg
dirmngr[20243.0]: DBG: chan_3 -> # Config: [none]
# Config: [none]
dirmngr[20243.0]: DBG: chan_3 -> OK Dirmngr 2.1.0 at your service
OK Dirmngr 2.1.0 at your service
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer man but i had a different problem it seems.

Comment: I use and recommend seahorse Keys and Passwords, for key management, the answer was to address the question.